# How should I structure my arrays

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, data-structures

I am a swift and iOS beginner and I am working on an app that will mostly feature tableviews of editable data.

[image]

The example from Apple's tableview programming guide is a lot like my app in structure.  Although my app will be using people and teams, to make it clear I will refer to Apple's example. Using Figure 3-1 as a reference I would like to be able to add, edit and delete Regions, add, edit and delete trails and to edit the properties of the trails.  I have succeeded with the trails array and trails properties but now I find I need to organize the trails into regions as well.  Should the regions array be an array of array of trails?

I apologize if the question is too broad but I don't know how else to ask it at this stage.  I have tried various approaches but one way or the other the data doesn't get edited correctly.

I am just looking for hint of which way to proceed since I have spent many days wrestling with this.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm pretty grossed out that theyre using an array of arrays which store the end data as dictionaries, rather than classes or structs

Comment: I should add that I have a region class and a trail class already.  I'm just looking for a "best practices" data structure since I am learning through trial and error, books and tutorials.  No one sitting next to me to bounce questions off of unfortunately.

Comment: "but one way or the other the data doesn't get edited correctly" Then that is what to ask about. You should show _your_ code and explain what the issue is. Otherwise the question _is_ too broad. SO is not really the place for questions containing "should". :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have two structs of region and trail. something like below:

```
struct Trail {
    var location: String
    var distance: Double
    var difficulty: String
}

struct Region {
    var name:String
    var trails: [Trail] // this will hold array of trails
}

var regionsArray: [Region] = []

// let create trails first
let trails = [
    Trail(location: "ABC", distance: 1.0, difficulty: "moderate"),
    Trail(location: "DEF", distance: 1.0, difficulty: "easy")
]

// then create region with its trails
let eastBay = Region(name: "East Bay", trails: trails)

// append and print array of regions
regionsArray.append(eastBay)
print(regionsArray.append)
```

Take note that This is just one way to add region with trails. You can have in loops or assign in array

Comment: Thanks, I'll go down this path.